# How to proceed with cert and key files to import to key store

Tags: java, web-services, keystore

I have a file name abc.cert and abc.key now i need to add this to a java key store, i have gone thru some already provided links in this site and also googled around to get the solution.

The prob is i am not able to change the files to .der b4 adding them to the jks.

i hv used open source openssl 64 bit for windows to convert the files from .pem to .der it opens up a config file and 0bite .der file.

could someone tell me where am missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to convert them to `.der` before adding them.

Just add them as they are. Are you getting an error or something?

Comment: i tried as you suggested, getting error: keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate

Comment: ok..i got it.  i downloaded the certficate which got in xxxx.pem format.  renamed it to xxxx.der format and was able to store it to keystore. but running into other exception "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
"